How can I get Sparrow Wallet to send change back to the origin address?
In the Electrum wallet, I could set use_change: false to send change back to the origin address. How can I achieve that with Sparrow Wallet?

What do you mean with "disable change address"? Do you want send change to a specific address or do you want to drop the change to the transaction fee? Could you please provide more details?

@Murch I want send change to origin address

Hi Moon soon, I edited your question to incorporate the information from your comment and reopened the topic. Please feel free to further edit the question post or roll back my change if you feel that I did not correctly express your intent.

Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/20621/5406, https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address_reuse
